# Leiningen Parent > Child > 3rd-Party Library Dependency Errors

Tags: maven, deployment, clojure, leiningen, datomic

I'm using leiningen to develop 2 projects simultaneously (see ***Checkout Dependencies*** [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md)). That's working and I've gotten it to a point where I want to deploy both libraries. Let's say they are ***lib-parent*** , which uses ***lib-child***.

Now, I've deployed *lib-child* to clojars (`lein deploy clojars`). But if I now include *lib-child* as a project dependency in *lib-parent*, I can't load *lib-child* because one of ***it's*** dependencies (Datomic and it's use of ***com.google.common.cache.Cache***) doesn't load. Running `(require 'lib-child.plugin)` at the repl will give me a ***ClassNotFoundException : com.google.common.cache.Cache***.

Is this ***i)*** a general leiningen dependency issue or ***ii)*** an issue with Datomic not getting all of it's dependencies? I'm using `[com.datomic/datomic-free "0.8.4143" :exclusions [org.slf4j/slf4j-nop org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j]]`.

```
user=> (require 'lib-child.plugin)
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.

ClassNotFoundException com.google.common.cache.Cache  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:366)
user=> (pst *e)
ExceptionInInitializerError 
        java.lang.Class.forName0 (Class.java:-2)
        java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:270)
        clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName (RT.java:2098)
        clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:430)
        clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:411)
        clojure.core/load/fn--5018 (core.clj:5530)
        clojure.core/load (core.clj:5529)
        clojure.core/load-one (core.clj:5336)
        clojure.core/load-lib/fn--4967 (core.clj:5375)
        clojure.core/load-lib (core.clj:5374)
        clojure.core/apply (core.clj:619)
        clojure.core/load-libs (core.clj:5413)
Caused by:
ClassNotFoundException com.google.common.cache.Cache
        java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:366)
        java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:355)
        java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:-2)
        java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:354)
        java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
        sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass (Launcher.java:308)
        java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
        java.lang.Class.forName0 (Class.java:-2)
        java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:190)
        datomic.cache__init.__init0 (:-1)
        datomic.cache__init.<clinit> (:-1)
        java.lang.Class.forName0 (Class.java:-2)
```

Thanks

Comment: have you confirmed the lib-child datomic dependency is in the generated pom.xml?

Comment: Also, when you run `lein deps :tree` in the lib-parent project, do you see `[com.google.guava/guava "14.0.1"]`?

Comment: @Jared314, Hey there. Yes, `lein deps :tree` yields ***[com.google.guava/guava "r09"]***. But that's under ***[com.datomic/datomic "0.8.3335" ...***, not ***[com.datomic/datomic-free "0.8.4143" ...***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed this. Removed all the `:exclusions`, in the Datomic declaration I used, in the ***lib-child*** project. Thanks to @hyPiRion on #leiningen @irc.freenode.org.